# Can we pass the beanshell assertion variable (in a thread) to cookie manager user defined variable (outside the thread) in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, session-cookies, assertions, beanshell

Can we pass the beanshell assertion variable (in a thread) to cookie manager user defined variable (outside the thread) in jmeter ?

[This is the image of user defined cookies which are been used on my request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ig1XT.png)

[This is bean shell variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lD7z.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will work this way, you can use something like:

1. In "init" thread group:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;

   CookieManager manager = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getProperty("HTTPSampler.cookie_manager").getObjectValue();
   props.put("cookiecount",String.valueOf(manager.getCookieCount()));
   for (int i=0;i<manager.getCookieCount();i++){
       // code to convert Cookie information to JMeter Properties
       props.put("cookie_name_" + i, manager.get(i).getName());
       //…..
   }
   ```
2. In "Action" thread group:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;
   import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.JMeterProperty;

   CookieManager manager = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getProperty("HTTPSampler.cookie_manager").getObjectValue();
   int count = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("cookiecount"));
   for (int i=0;i<count;i++) {
       Cookie cookie = new Cookie(props.getProperty("cookie_name"+i),props.getProperty("cookie_value"+i), props.getProperty("cookie_domain"+i),props.getProperty("cookie_path"+i), Boolean.parseBoolean(props.getProperty("cookie_secure"+i)), Long.parseLong(props.getProperty("cookie_expires"+i)));
       manager.add(cookie);
   }

   JMeterProperty cookieprop = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getProperty("HTTPSampler.cookie_manager");
   cookieprop.setObjectValue(manager);
   ctx.getCurrentSampler().setProperty(myprop);
   ```
3. Instead of having global HTTP Cookie Manager it is better to use 2 (or 3) separate ones local to the [Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group).
4. Consider moving to [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) and Groovy language as Beanshell performance might be a big question mark in case of high loads. See [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) article for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, i would try to implement it. Moreover i have not taken local cookie managers coz i have the session ID generated in the request in Init thread only. So, i would have to extract the session Id and other cookies from Init thread and need to parse them in Action thread.          I thought it would be better to extract the variable and replace it in Global cookie manager, so that from there user defined cookies can be used by following request in any thread.....

Comment: Please suggest is it a wise approach or not. And if it would be quite complex to implement, please suggest a better method for it.